# Scraping with CasperJS: page seems to load without javascript enabled

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, google-search, casperjs

I am trying to scrape book genre information from google.

Much like when you put a calculation/conversion into google, the result displays in a box above the search results. I can scrape the data within this box in the browser (console) quite easily, however when I attempt the same code within casper, the content boxes don't appear anywhere in the code. The only way I can replicate this in browser is if I turn JS off.

I'm not sure why a different format is displayed to CasperJS and my own browser, but is there a way to get them to be the same? Here is the current code I am using, where

links= https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#safe=off&hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=The+Love+Affairs+of+a+Bibliomaniac+book+genre&oq=The+Love+Affairs+of+a+Bibliomaniac+book+genre

```
casper.start();
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36        (KHTML, like Gecko) ');
casper.thenOpen(links, function() {

casper.waitForSelector('.answer_predicate', function() {
this.echo(this.getHTML('.answer_predicate'));

});



});
casper.run();
}
```

Comment: Ive never used casper or anything but looking at your code is it that `this.echo(this.getHTML('answer_predicate'));` should be `this.echo(this.getHTML('.answer_predicate'));` you forgot the dot before answer_predicate

Comment: @PAEz sorry that was a typo. casper.waitForSelector times out before that code gets any chance to run and it seems the page CasperJS is loading is different to the page that I get in browser. .answer_predicate exists on the link above when you check it in the browser but not when the same URL is opened through CasperJS

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I had a good look at it and I couldnt figure it out either.  Noticed your new to SO and so dont have any rep, I do and am interested in the myself, would you like me to put a bounty on it?  Maybe that would get you some more help.

Comment: @PAEz I persisted with it for a while. I dumped out the HTML of the page from CasperJS and it seems that the only way I could get a similar result in-browser was to disable JS. The strange thing is I have executed casperJS on JS/jQuery pages before with success so I'm truly baffled.

I attempted to set a userAgent also to try to see if it would affect the outcome of the page but I'm not sure if I did it correctly.

Any help on this would be appreciated :)

Comment: Like I said never used that stuff before but had a go and I couldn't figure it either.  Tried changing the user agent, which did make things change but didn't help.  Noticed it was getting redirected so blocked that (which was a pain), but that didn't help.  The only thing I didn't get around to because I didn't have it set up and was to tired, was to sniff the headers to see if theres any difference.  Ohwell, hopefully the bounty will help you get some notice/help.  OH, and update your question so that error isnt in there and fill in the whole useragent.  Less work = more chance of answer.

Comment: If an answer works for you please remember to tick it so I know to give them the bounty...if it doesnt you should prolly tell them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the following:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false,
    loadPlugins: false,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1588.0 Safari/537.36'
  }
});

links = 'https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#safe=off&hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=The+Love+Affairs+of+a+Bibliomaniac+book+genre&oq=The+Love+Affairs+of+a+Bibliomaniac+book+genre'

casper.start();

casper.thenOpen(links, function() {
  this.waitForSelector('.answer_predicate', function() {
    this.echo(this.getHTML('.answer_predicate'));
    this.echo(this.getElementInfo('.answer_predicate').text);
  });
});

casper.run();
```

Gives me this output:

```
<span class="kno-a-v">Fiction</span>
Fiction
```

My assumption is that the problem here is the same as the one posted [here](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/pull/572).

Comment: Didnt work for me, but if it works for @Khaled Shaaban and he gives you the tick Ill give you the bounty.

Comment: @PAEz What version of CasperJS/PhantomJS are you running? I've got 1.1-beta1/1.9.1 (respectively) myself.

Answer (score 0):

@PAEz: Try this script, is pretty similar to the one hexid created, but is done with phantomjs-only (no casperjs).

Btw, since hexid answered first and I'm doing something pretty similar, I think he is the one that deserves the bounty.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36';
page.open('https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&cad=b&fp=c210d6fe329544e7&hl=en&q=The+Love+Affairs+of+a+Bibliomaniac+book+genre&safe=off', function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var genre = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.getElementsByClassName('answer_predicate')[0].textContent;
        });
        console.log(genre);
    }, 3000);
});
```

I'm using phantomjs 1.9.1 btw.